# What is the maximum area of a hexagon (not regular) with 5 sides that are 12 units long and the other side being x units long?

Tags: geometry, optimization, area

Here's what I'm trying to figure out:

There is a hexagon (not a regular hexagon) with 5 sides that are 12 units long and one side that is unknown. How does one find the maximum area of the hexagon, and what is the length of the unknown side when the area is maximized?

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Consider the symmetric of the hexagon wr to the side of unknown length. Together with the original one it forms a decagon with all $10$ sides of length $12$ and double the area. So the problem is equivalent to maximizing the area of this decagon. The area is maximal if and only if it is a regular decagon. The unknown length will be the diameter of this decagon, call it $D$. Now $12 = D \sin \frac{\pi}{10}$, so you can get $D$.